# Draggable pie chart with percentages

Tags: javascript, canvas

I found this nice canvas pie on Github, but it's giving me some problem. I'm not very good in JS, so I'm here asking for help. https://github.com/jamesalvarez/draggable-piechart

I’m trying to add in each section the percentages that you can see in the table below the chart in github example. I don’t need + and  -, I only need the percentages in the pie sections and updating when the user drag the sections.

I tried in any way, but it seems very hard.

```
      '" class="adjust-button" data-i="' +
      i +
      '" data-d="-1">&#43;</div>';
      var minus =
      '<div id="min-' +
      data[i] +
      '" class="adjust-button" data-i="' +
      i +
      '" data-d="1">&#8722;</div>';
      propsRow += "<td>" + v + plus + minus + "</td>";
    }window.CP.exitedLoop(15);
    labelsRow += "</tr>";
    propsRow += "</tr>";

    table.innerHTML = labelsRow + propsRow;

    var adjust = document.getElementsByClassName("adjust-button");

    function adjustClick(e) {
      var i = this.getAttribute("data-i");
      var d = this.getAttribute("data-d");

      piechart.moveAngle(i, d * 0.1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < adjust.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(16)) break;
      adjust[i].addEventListener("click", adjustClick);
    }window.CP.exitedLoop(16);
  }
})();
```

Here my codepen if it can be useful.

https://codepen.io/Waterbear83/pen/vYOrbva

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

That sample code you dropped is from the `function onPieChartChange` ...
But what you need to add is on `function drawSegment`

Where they do `fillText` we just add the percentage

```
var p = Math.round(100 * arcSize / (Math.PI * 2))
context.fillText(format.label + " " + p + "%", dx, dy);
```

Here is a working example:
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/draggable-piechart/master/example2.html
(I've only tested in google chrome)

---

...and please in the future reduce your problem to a small code sample,
you can not expect people to help when you drop 800 lines of code.

Comment: can i use this for react-native